# Как получить ссылки на изображения в css файле?

Tags: python, парсер, parse

Есть файл `main.css`:

```
header {
    color: black;
    font-size: 32px;
    background-image: url('images/bg.jpeg');
}

.infoBlock {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    background-image: url('images/info.jpeg');
}

.contactBlock {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
}
```

Из этого файла нужно вытянуть все ссылки на избражения в стиле `background-image` игнорируя векторные изображения как в селекторе `.contactBlock`

**Мой вопрос**: Есть ли удобные библиотеки для парсинга `css` файлов по типу `BeautifulSoup`?

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать модуль [`cssutils`](https://pypi.org/project/cssutils/)

```py
import cssutils
from pprint import pprint

css = u'''
    body, html { color: blue }
    h1, h2 { font-size: 1.5em; color: red}
    h3, h4, h5 { font-size: small; }
'''

dct = {}
sheet = cssutils.parseString(css)

for rule in sheet:
    selector = rule.selectorText
    styles = rule.style.cssText
    dct[selector] = styles


pprint(dct)
```

**Output:**

```py
{
    u'body, html': u'color: blue',
    u'h1, h2': u'font-size: 1.5em;\ncolor: red',
    u'h3, h4, h5': u'font-size: small'
}
```

Соответственно можешь в переменную `css` запихнуть содержимое файла через следующую функцию:

```py
def get_css(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8"):
        return filename.read()


css = get_css("main.css")
```